# Current Source in a circuit

Tags: voltage, current-source

In a circuit, I've been asked to calculate a current in a certain branch using the node voltage method. My question pertains to the fact that the circuit I was given contains a current source, and I don't know how to factor that into equations for the branch method or the node method.

Since it is a circuit element is there a node before and after the current source? And does the source have any resistance (my guess is no)? If it doesn't have any resistance that would mean the node voltages before and after it are equal?

And if I'm doing the branch method of solving how do I count it as a branch, if at all?
[image: given problem]

Comment: Voltage at node is still current times resistance

Comment: What do you mean

Comment: http://www.calvin.edu/~svleest/circuitExamples/NodeVoltageMeshCurrent/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a nice schematic editor on this site. You should use it:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f5qokh.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I've labeled the nodes above and made a choice about which one I decided to call \$0\:\textrm{V}\$. You really only need to know the values for \$V_X\$, \$V_Z\$, and \$R_4\$ to figure out the current, \$I\$, using the obvious equation for the given arrow direction, \$I=\frac{V_Z-V_X}{R_4}\$. \$V_Y\$ isn't needed (though you could include it.) So you only need to solve the following:

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{V_X}{R_2}+\frac{V_X}{R_4} &= \frac{V}{R_2}+\frac{V_Z}{R_4} + I_1\\\\ \frac{V_Z}{R_3}+\frac{V_Z}{R_4}+I_1 &= \frac{V_X}{R_4}
\end{align*}$$

In matrix form, it's:

$$\begin{align*}
V_X\cdot\left(\frac{1}{R_2}+\frac{1}{R_4}\right)+V_Z\cdot\frac{-1}{R_4}&=\frac{V}{R_2}+I_1\\\\V_X\cdot\frac{-1}{R_4}+V_Z\cdot\left(\frac{1}{R_3}+\frac{1}{R_4}\right)&=-I_1
\end{align*}$$

And you can either solve that symbolically or numerically, if you have values handy. With the values in hand, you can then figure out \$I\$.

---

A symbolic solution could be done in the following way. Multiply equation 1 by \$R_2\vert\vert R_4\$:

$$\begin{align*}
V_X\cdot 1+V_Z\cdot\frac{-\left(R_2\vert\vert R_4\right)}{R_4}&=\left(R_2\vert\vert R_4\right)\cdot\left(\frac{V}{R_2}+I_1\right)
\\\\
V_X\cdot\frac{-1}{R_4}+V_Z\cdot\left(\frac{1}{R_3}+\frac{1}{R_4}\right)&=-I_1
\end{align*}$$

Now, zero out \$V_X\$ in the second equation by adding to it the first equation multiplied by \$\frac{1}{R_4}\$:

$$\begin{align*}
V_X\cdot 1+V_Z\cdot\frac{-\left(R_2\vert\vert R_4\right)}{R_4}&=\left(R_2\vert\vert R_4\right)\cdot\left(\frac{V}{R_2}+I_1\right)
\\\\
V_X\cdot 0+V_Z\cdot\left(\frac{1}{R_3}+\frac{1}{R_4}-\frac{\left(R_2\vert\vert R_4\right)}{R_4^2}\right)&=-I_1+\frac{R_2\vert\vert R_4}{R_4}\cdot\left(\frac{V}{R_2}+I_1\right)
\end{align*}$$

Divide the second equation so that \$V_Z\$ is multiplied by 1:

$$\begin{align*}
V_X\cdot 1+V_Z\cdot\frac{-\left(R_2\vert\vert R_4\right)}{R_4}&=\left(R_2\vert\vert R_4\right)\cdot\left(\frac{V}{R_2}+I_1\right)
\\\\
V_X\cdot 0+V_Z\cdot 1&=\frac{-I_1+\frac{R_2\vert\vert R_4}{R_4}\cdot\left(\frac{V}{R_2}+I_1\right)}{\frac{1}{R_3}+\frac{1}{R_4}-\frac{\left(R_2\vert\vert R_4\right)}{R_4^2}}
\end{align*}$$

Now, multiply the second equation by \$\frac{R_2\vert\vert R_4}{R_4}\$ and add that into the first equation to zero out \$V_Z\$:

$$\begin{align*}
V_X&=\left(R_2\vert\vert R_4\right)\cdot\left(\frac{V}{R_2}+I_1\right)+\frac{R_2\vert\vert R_4}{R_4}\cdot V_Z
\\\\
&=\left(R_2\vert\vert R_4\right)\cdot\left[\frac{V}{R_2}+\frac{V_Z}{R_4}+I_1\right]
\\\\
V_Z&=\frac{-I_1\cdot R_4+\left(R_2\vert\vert R_4\right)\cdot\left(\frac{V}{R_2}+I_1\right)}{1+\frac{R_4}{R_3}-\frac{\left(R_2\vert\vert R_4\right)}{R_4}}
\end{align*}$$

Remember that \$I=\frac{V_Z-V_X}{R_4}\$, so if you are really wanting to have fun with algebra, plug in the values and simplify further.

Comment: Thank you!! So does a VZ and Vy have the same voltage then theoretically? And what if there was no resistor after after the current source? Would that make the current source a perfect conductor and all the current would bypass the other branches? How does a current source work alone?

Comment: @UALHunter Too many questions! But suppose you remove the current source. Then \$R_5\$ would have no voltage drop and \$V_Y=V_X\$. Is there any reason why you'd believe that \$V_Z=V_X\$ in any fundamental way? Why would adding a current source, which forces \$V_Y=V_X+R_5\cdot I_1\$, make you think it would then force \$V_Z=V_X\$? In general, the answer is no. (A current source as infinite impedance, not zero impedance. In a sense, it's the opposite of a perfect conductor. So you need to get rid of that idea.)

Comment: Wait if I removed the current source how would the voltage drop across R5 be 0? Wouldn't the current from the voltage source branch out across R5 as it normally would?

Comment: @UALHunter When I say "remove" I mean remove (not short.) One end of \$R_5\$ is then hanging out there, unattached. Since it is unattached, there's no current. Since there is no current, there is no voltage difference across it. Since there is no voltage difference across it, both ends are at the same potential. Therefore, \$V_Y=V_X\$ in this case.

Comment: Ok but then what about Vz and Vy? How do their voltages differ mathematically and why do they differ. Is their a voltage difference across a current source?

Comment: @UALHunter A current source doesn't have to have a voltage difference across it. Put a wire across it. But if there is any resistance at all across its terminals then there will be a voltage difference. In your circuit, so long as \$R_4\$ and \$R_5\$ aren't both zero, there will be a voltage across the current source.

Comment: But if there is a voltage difference across the current source, how can one picture that? Would the difference across R5 just be I(R5)? And the difference across Vz and Vx is just the current across R4 times R4? So if Vz - Vx is smaller than Vy - Vx, that means Vz - Vy is negative? And if Vz - Vx is greater than Vy-Vx, then Vz - Vy is the positive difference between (Vz- Vx) and (Vy-Vx)?

Comment: @UALHunter Suppose \$V_1=10\:\textrm{V}, I_1=1\:\textrm{mA}, R_1=1\:\textrm{k}\Omega, R_2=2\:\textrm{k}\Omega,\$ etc. Then \$V_X=8\frac{2}{3}\:\textrm{V}, V_Y=13\frac{2}{3}\:\textrm{V}, V_Z=2\:\textrm{V}\$. The drop across \$R_5\$ must be \$5\:\textrm{V}\$. If you increase \$I_1\$, \$V_Z\$ will go lower, \$V_X\$ will go higher, and \$V_Y\$ will go higher, too.

Comment: Ok this makes more sense now. So the current between Vx and Vz really flows from Vx to Vz and not the other way around. Also hypothetically speaking, if the current in another circuit actually flowed from Vz to Vx, would the voltage difference between Vz and Vx have to be the same as the difference if I went from Vz to Vy to Vx (assuming I1 still flowed that way)?

Comment: @UALHunter I'm not so glad it's making more sense, since the rest of what you say is confused, I think. The direction of the current through \$R_4\$ is just a matter of a sign. It doesn't help you to make a mental decision about which way, in sum, it is going. That's not something you get to decide, arbitrarily. If \$V_1=-10\:\textrm{V}\$, then it would have an opposite sign, for example, keeping \$I_1=1\:\textrm{mA}\$. The whole circuit matters. Are you able to solve the matrix I gave you, symbolically? The resulting expression for I would help this discussion a lot.

Comment: Your equation makes sense and I was able to replicate it on my own, but I'm stuck as to how to get rid of Vx and Vz and put it only in terms of the resistances and I1 and V. Also correct me please now because this is how I see it: current source is just another element in a circuit and it is connected to nodes like a regular element. The voltage drop across it is arbitrary and depends on the given circuit? So is it possible to do a voltage law equation with it in the loop?

Comment: @UALHunter Yes, the voltage drop across the current source/sink depends on the circuit it is attached to. Which should make sense as it must _drive_ that current through whatever impedance it faces. And the impedance depends upon the circuit it's connected up into. A voltage source needs to maintain the voltage, also regardless of the circuit. So the current it supplies _also_ depends upon the circuit it is attached to, as well. Don't you see the parallels here?

Comment: Yes I see that parallel. But if I wanted to do a Kirchoff's loop rule with a loop of circuit branches, do I write the drop across I1 as V1 and that's it? I can't define a resistance for it right? And In regards to your equation, I simplified and got i (the variable I wanted) = -(V + IR2 + IR3) / (R2 + R3)

Comment: Also if I had an arbitrary circuit with just one battery a resistor and a current source, and the resistor and current source were attached in parallel so there are only two nodes, would the voltage drop across both by default have to be the voltage of the battery? In this case it is possible to guess the drop?

Comment: @UALHunter I've added some algebraic stuff at the end. In any case, this is where I need to leave it. Enough time here. You need to rummage around in your head and work through a few things, now.